# Financial support for Ubuntu Edge

Tags: ubuntu-edge

How can I provide financial support for "Ubuntu Edge"? Give me a link please.

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu edge is long ago dead.It failed to reach it's target of 32million$.The Edge fell short of its funding goal, raising only $12,809,906.

Read the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_Edge) and [indiegogo campaign page](http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge?).

You can't do anything for now.Maybe hope that canonical restarts the plan again someday.